# How do I receive a JSON object from PHP backend and convert to JavaScript array for frontend

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a backend in php that is returning a json object to a React frontend. 
The object arrives in this format

```
{data: Array(401), status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
 config: {url: "http://localhost/index.php", method: "post", headers: {…}, transformRequest: 
 Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
 data: Array(401)
 [0 … 99]
  0: {id: "191", name: "Thunder", description: null, created: "2012-10-04 12:36:29", slug: "thunder", …}
  1: {id: "95", name: "Break", description: null, created: "2010-03-26 13:19:11", slug: "break", …}
```

etc.

I want to take this object and grab the data array and then loop the array.
This is what I have so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Container extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
    };
   }

   componentDidMount() {
   axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
      timeout: 4000,          
    })
    .then(response => {
      this.setState({data:response})
    })

    .catch(error => console.error('timeout exceeded'))

  }

   render() {
    const {data} = this.state;
    const items = Object.values(data).map(function(num) {
      return num
    });        
      return (
          <div>
            {items}
          </div>
      )
  }

}

export default Container;
```

This throws an error of

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, description, created, slug, image, tags}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

If I wrap the items[0] in JSON.stringify I get a string, but I want to convert the response object to an array so I can use `data.map(item => etc)`.

Update:

```
num = num = (401) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}  
[0 … 99]
0: {id: "191", name: "Thunder", description: null, created: "2012-10-04 12:36:29", slug: "thunder", …}
1: {id: "95", name: "Break", description: null, created: "2010-03-26 13:19:11", slug: "break", …} etc etc
```

Comment: shouldnt you want setState({data:response.data}), instead of simply response and then loop through that array instead of looping through an object.

Comment: @Kevin.a 's answer is right. you don't have to convert it to an Array because it already is an Array. Although your using the entire response instead of just the returned data.

Comment: I already use setState({data:response}) I want to map the this.state.data

Comment: @BarryWatts Just for the sake of understanding, "JSON Object" is a misnomer. JSON is short for JavaScript Object Notation. It is a way to represent javascript data structures as a string. There is no such thing as a JSON object. What you are getting from your backend is just "JSON"

Comment: @marie if i console.log(typeof data); it returns object

Comment: @BarryWatts, the response object passed to your `.then` function is not just the data your server sent. The data sent from your server (the data you want to render) is inside the `data` property of the response object. So you should use `response.data`, as Kevin indicated

Comment: @isick  I have done that and it returns this error 
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, description, created, slug, image, tags}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: @BarryWatts Your `.map` function is just returning an array of the actual object literals. As React is indicating to you, it cannot render an object literal. What does an object with property `id` look like in a browser? You need to use those items to generate renderable content (component, function, string, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok so with some of the answers and a little more experimenting this is what I have and its a start to the rest of the solution

I changed this line

```
 this.setState({data:response})
```

to

```
 this.setState({data:response.data})
```

and changed the render to this

```
  render() {
    const {data} = this.state
    let result = [];
    Object.values(data).map(num =>
      result.push(num)
     );
    return (
          <div>
            {result.map(tile => 
             `<div><img src='${tile.image}'/></div>` 
              )}
          </div>
      )
  }
```

Comment: I wonder why do you need `Object.values()` if `response.data` is supposed to be an array...

Comment: You can set your answer as the accepted answer, that will help others with similar questions.

Comment: You don't need to map and push, just do `let result = Object.values(data);` since you're not actually mapping anything, or just `let result = data;` if `data` is already an array.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Pass the array directly to the state instead of passing an object. This way you can loop directly through the array instead of the object values.

```
import React from 'react';
    import axios from 'axios';

    class Container extends React.Component{
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          data: [],
        };
       }

       componentDidMount() {
       axios({
          method: 'post',
          url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
          timeout: 4000,          
        })
        .then(response => {
          this.setState({data:response.data})
        })

        .catch(error => console.error('timeout exceeded'))

      }

       render() {
        const {data} = this.state;
        const items = data.map(function(num) {
          return num.id;
        });        
          return (
              <div>
                {items}
              </div>
          )
      }

    }

    export default Container;
```

Comment: this returns 
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name, description, created, slug, image, tags}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Hmm, thats odd. I thought response.data is an array

Comment: @Kevin.a it is, but his (your) map function is just returning the same object literal when it should be mapping those objects into components

Comment: @BarryWatts I dont know what data you want, but i changed the code and took the id. If you want the whole object you could just push them into an array for example.

Answer (score -1):

Use `.setState()`. It will make react re-render the page.
Also, what's the value of `num` in your function? Might want to check that

Comment: num = (401) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}  
[0 … 99]
0: {id: "191", name: "Thunder", description: null, created: "2012-10-04 12:36:29", slug: "thunder", …}
1: {id: "95", name: "Break", description: null, created: "2010-03-26 13:19:11", slug: "break", …} etc etc

Comment: @BarryWatts Please add it your question, not in a comment. That way other people can see it too without digging in the comments.

Comment: @Camilo added to question